# How to get the path to the source file?

Tags: c#, abbyy

After recognition, I get `IDocument`. This entity has pages. I can not get the path to the source file for the page.

That's what i have:

```
 IEnumerable<IImageDocument> listFlexiImages
```

I load into the processor in this way:

```
foreach (IImageDocument image in listFlexiImages)
{
   _processor.AddImageDocument(image);
}
```

Where _processor this IFlexiCaptureProcessor

Then I perform recognition:

```
flexiDoc= _processor.RecognizeNextDocument();
```

I need to get the path to the source file for each page of this document.

```
for (var i = 0; i < flexiDoc.Pages.Count; i++)
{
    var path = flexiDoc.Pages.Item(i).OriginalImagePath;
}
```

But the path to the source file is empty for some reason.

In other words, I need to throw `IImageDocument` objects to the processor and, when performing recognition, I want to get an `IDocument` object from which the stars know their source file.

Comment: How do you construct the list of `IImageDocuments` to begin with?

Comment: This makes the classifier, there are templates for classification.

In the classifier, I upload source file paths to the processor. 
              _processor.AddImageFile(pathToFile);                                         
 Next, I execute the same _processor.RecognizeNextDocument () method;           And I get a IDocument that has IImageDocuments

Comment: IDocument.Pages[0].Image

Comment: Source files like IDocuments can be many